# shape.xml No interface appears

Tags: android

I have created a "shape xml" file but it does not appear and when I use it , it does not change the shape of the button

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? You haven't provide `<solid>` or  `<stroke>` .

Answer (score 0):

You just define an empty rectangular shape, nothing more, so what do you expect?

Add a `<solid>` for fill color, `<stroke>` for stroke, or `corner radius`

Comment: The example use `android:shape="oval"`, which make it circular, and you used `rectangle` shape, which is already rectangle in the preview.